# Plotting Datetime objects with PyQtGraph

Tags: python, datetime, pyqtgraph

I am new to PyQtGraph and need help plotting datetime objects on the x-axis which can easily be done with matplotlib. Any help would be appreciated.

As a simple version of what Id like to do see below where I want to plot the datetime objects displayed as the ticks on the x-axis.

The code throws an error as this cannot be done.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import datetime

datetimes = ['2014-10-01 00:00:00', '2014-10-02 00:00:00', '2014-10-03 00:00:00']
x = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for i in datetimes]
y = [1,2,3]


win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title = 'plotting')
p1 = win.addPlot(row=1, col=0, title = 'test')
p1.plot(x,y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Answer (score 8):

pyqtgraph now natively supports DateTime format: https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/dateaxisitem.html?highlight=DateAxisItem

It is quite straightforward, if you have timestamps on the x-axis, just do:

```
axis = DateAxisItem()
plot.setAxisItems({'bottom':axis})
```

Answer (score 4):

A working example with custom AxisItem on git: [pg_time_axis.py](https://gist.github.com/cpascual/cdcead6c166e63de2981bc23f5840a98).

If using PyQt5, change the import in the `__main__` function to `from PyQt5 import QtGui`

[image: datetime axis zoom 1] [image: datetime axis zoom 2]

PS: It would be really nice to see the [PR](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/pull/74), mentioned by Luke, to be finally merged.

Answer (score 2):

As you have found, pyqtgraph does not support plotting with datetime objects. You need to convert these to numerical value before plotting.

For static zoom, you can also use `AxisItem.setTicks()` to customize the text displayed on the axis.

If you want to be able to zoom the axis, then you need to make an `AxisItem` subclass that overrides `tickValues` and `tickStrings`. You can see the docstrings here: https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/AxisItem.py#L661

..and as an example, there is an open PR that attempts what you are doing here: https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/pull/74

Comment: Hi Luke. Do you perhaps have an example of this? I have been able to rename the floats according to datetime but I need it to auto adjust based on the zoom level of the user